# How to remove item from pop up menu in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am working on matlab gui. 
I stop on drop down menu. 
How to remove item from pop up menu ?

I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: are you talking about the *pop-up-menu* uicontrol?

Comment: could you please post your code?

Comment: Yes, I mean popup menu.

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically/dynamically?

Comment: Yes . I have in popupmenu strTab.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have tagged your question with `matlab-guide` I consider you are working with it:

1. mark your *pop-up-menu*-uicontrol
2. right click and choose the *property editor*
3. click on the icon beside the *String*-property
4. enter or delete the desired entries

entries have to be separated by a new line.